# Embedding partially ordered spaces in a product of chains

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I've been thinking about the following construction recently and was wondering whether it is something used in the literature, and whether it is cannonical? As the title suggests, it is a way to embed a partial order in a product of totally ordered spaces.

Let $P$ be a partially ordered space, and $\mathcal{C}(P)$ be the collection of chains over $P$. Then we can embed $\mathfrak{e}:P\to \underset{C\in \mathcal{C}(P)}{\times}C$ by the following definition:

If $p\in C$, then $\mathfrak{e}$ maps to an element whose $C$-th coordinate is $p$. Moreover for all $C\in \mathcal{C}(P)$ choose an arbitrary element $e_C\in P$, and if $p\notin C$ define the $C$-th coordinate of $\mathfrak{e}(p)$ to be $e_C$. More specifically

$$ \Big[\mathfrak{e}(p) \Big](C)= \begin{cases} p & ,p\in C\\ e_C &, p\notin C \end{cases} $$

In the case where there are maximal chains, we can consider instead of $\mathcal{C}(P)$ an alternative collection $\tilde{\mathcal{C}}(P)$, where if $C'$ is a maximal chain on $P$, then we omit all chains contained in $C'$ from $\tilde{\mathcal{C}}(P)$.

Is this sort of construction standard? Is there perhaps a better procedure known in the literature?

Comment: To me it seems, that the construction above isn't an embedding in general. Let $P$ be a two element set with the partial order given by $=$. Then there are two one element chains, hence the product of the chains has one element. Hence $P$ cannot be embedded in the product.

Comment: Even if you handle cases like the one mentioned above, this construction seems to be far from canonincal as you are using choice to find the $e_C$s, unless of course you have some way of choosing these elements without invoking choice in some specific context.(maybe when the base set of the p.o. is well-ordered by some auxiliary order)

Comment: One quick fix however, would be to look at the product $\Pi_{C\subseteq P} (C\cup\{*\})$, where you do what you did before, but use $*$ instead of $e_C$, where $*$ is something $\not \in P$. This will probably solve the other problem as well. [For more percision and to take the order into account, let $C_* = C\cup\{*\}$ and let $*$ be greater than all of $C$'s elements. Now look at the product order $\Pi_{C\subseteq P} C_*$.]

Answer (score 1):

Just to give closure to the question, the most relevant notion for my question that I was able to find, is the one used in defining the [Order dimension of a poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_dimension).